# Adding time limitation in maze game

Tags: java

I am making a maze game in Java. I have made a maze board, A start point and a end point. When i reach the end point then it exit and show a winning message. But i can not add a time limitation. Suppose player have to reach the end point with 30 seconds otherwise he lose the game.

Comment: Why can't you add a time limitation?

Comment: And your question is? "Give me code that counts down"? 

What have you tried?

Comment: Yes i need the code. please no more question, if you know then give the answer.

Answer (score 1):

`System.currentTimeMillis();` // returns current time in milliseconds...

//save time at beggining of game, compare saved time to current time... when x time has passed... do something...

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#currentTimeMillis()

Answer (score 1):

You have to basically create a separate thread which will take care of the time counter. To see how to create a thread you can refer

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/runthread.html

After this you need to run the game on a separate thread and counter on another thread..To make a time counter you can take help from this previous post.

[How can I count the time it takes a function to complete in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/692569/how-can-i-count-the-time-it-takes-a-function-to-complete-in-java)

Answer (score 1):

Get current system time when you start a game: 
`long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();`

Than every time your tick/update method occours check how much time elapsed: 
`long elapsedTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;`

elapsedTime holds elapsed time in miliseconds to get elapsed time in seconds just divide it with 1000: 
`elapsedTime\= 1000;`

Now you can check how much time passed since the game was started, 
For example:
`if(elapsedTime >= 30) running = false;`

Have in mind that this is simplest implementation just to give you some idea of how it can be done in Java

Comment: thanks it works properly. here is the total code i have done so far..http://emontec.blogspot.com/2013/04/maze-game-source-code-in-java.html