# Optimized way to count number of occurrences of a digit in a range of numbers

Tags: java, algorithm, optimization

I've been trying to find the most optimized way to compute the number of occurrences of each digit from 0 to 9 in a random range of numbers typed in by the user for a random personal project.
Say, the user enters 1 as the lower bound (inclusive) and 20 as the upper bound (inclusive). Output should be like this:

```
2 12 3 2 2 2 2 2 2 2
```

User can only enter positive integers.
Now, the below code runs fine for small range of numbers/ small bounds, however, as expected it takes 4 seconds+ on my laptop for large numbers/range.
I've been trying to find a way to make things quicker, I used modulus to get the digits thinking maybe string conversion is to blame, but it didn't increase speed that much. I want to reduce runtime to less than 2 seconds. There must be a way, but what? Here is my original code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CountDigitsRandomRange {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        String g = s.nextLine();

        while (!g.equals("0 0")) {
            String[] n = g.split(" ");
            long x = Long.parseLong(n[0]);
            long y = Long.parseLong(n[1]);

            long zero = 0;
            long one = 0;
            long two = 0;
            long three = 0;
            long four = 0;
            long five = 0;
            long six = 0;
            long seven = 0;
            long eight = 0;
            long nine = 0;

            for (long i = x; i <= y; i++) {
                String temp = String.valueOf(i);

                for (int j = 0; j < temp.length(); j++) {
                    if (temp.charAt(j) == '0') {
                        zero++;
                    }
                    if (temp.charAt(j) == '1') {
                        one++;
                    }
                    if (temp.charAt(j) == '2') {
                        two++;
                    }
                    if (temp.charAt(j) == '3') {
                        three++;
                    }
                    if (temp.charAt(j) == '4') {
                        four++;
                    }
                    if (temp.charAt(j) == '5') {
                        five++;
                    }
                    if (temp.charAt(j) == '6') {
                        six++;
                    }
                    if (temp.charAt(j) == '7') {
                        seven++;
                    }
                    if (temp.charAt(j) == '8') {
                        eight++;
                    }
                    if (temp.charAt(j) == '9') {
                        nine++;
                    }
                }
            }
            System.out.println(zero + " " + one + " " + two + " "+three + " " + four
             + " " + five + " " + six + " " + seven + " " + eight + " " + nine);
            g=s.nextLine();
        }
    }
}
```

I've seen some solutions online similar to my issue but they're mostly in C/C++, I don't get the syntax.

Comment: Why go through the expensive operation of splitting the string? You can just loop through each char in the entire string and use switch-case to increment the counter for the number it matches. That should be the fastest solution possible.

Comment: @magicmn nah, it still takes some time. Maybe there's a better way to do this with dynamic programming but can't figure out how.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple implementation that uses modulus. If you want a faster code, you will need to find some smart formula that gives you the result without performing the actual computation.

```java
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Counter
{
    private static long[] counts = new long[10];

    public static void count(long x, long y)
    {
        Arrays.fill(counts, 0);
        for(long val=x; val<=y; val++)
            count(val);
    }

    public static void count(long val)
    {
        while(val>0)
        {
            int digit = (int)(val % 10);
            counts[digit]++;
            val /= 10;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        count(1, 20);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(counts));
    }
}
```

Output:

```
[2, 12, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2]
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution. Your code is definitely much better than mine, but it still takes a long time for large numbers like 100000000 and 100000000. You're right, maybe it needs some smart solution where I don't actually compute anything

Comment: @Sammie: The larger the range, the longer it will take to calculate the result.  You can manage user expectations by printing a message if the range is large, say 10,000 or greater.  By the time they read and understand the message, your code will complete its calculations.

Answer (score 0):

So here is an issue you might not be aware of @Sammie. In my opinion, you should NOT use the seconds provided by your runner in Java to count time when it comes to making operations more efficient. As far as I am informed, a more objective calculation is to use internal methods of Java which depend on the CPU clock to count time. This way there is less variation between different PC's (although this I don't believe is fully eliminated). Please check my references below:

1. [Clock milis (only use this if you cannot use the solution below)](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/java-8-clock-millis-method-with-examples/)
2. [Nanoseconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/692569/how-can-i-count-the-time-it-takes-a-function-to-complete-in-java)

---

**Edit:** Here is [another stack overflow post discussing this matter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8423789/benchmarking-inside-java-code). Nanoseconds seem to be preferable.

All you need to do after that is convert into minutes, and you should now be calculating more precisely.

Comment: You shouldn't use either to measure and compare performance of operations.The JVM needs some time to "warm-up" and repeating the process a few thousand times will reduce most of the randomness that a single test can give. So better to use a benchmarking library instead.

Comment: @magicmn I was not aware of benchmarking libraries for Java. I will take a look and potentially update my answer. Thanks for the info.

Comment: @NicktheCommunityScientist um, I just stated the time to give an idea of how long my users had to wait before they saw the results. Minutes/seconds/nanoseconds etc. internal calculation time won't matter to them. They'd like instantaneous results like my code gives with small values/range. That doesn't happen with big numbers like 1000000 and 100000000 which is why I posted this, so someone could guide me with a better version of it or tell me where I went wrong.

Comment: @Sammie Ok, that's fine. I guess I misinterpreted the question. I will see if I can help with that.